# Bluetooth adapter not working

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 20.04. Bought Bluetooth USB adapter and its not working. I plug it, adapter blinks for second and in Settings/Bluetooth instead No Bluetooth found(Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth.) I see Bluetooth Turned Off(Turn on to connect devices and receive file transfers). But When I turn it on nothing happens, bluetooth not enabling.

```
spci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0084 Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b38:0010 Gear Head 107-Key Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

*I also have another older USB Bluetooth adapter which is working but I would like to make this one work too.*